# MagicalRecord not saving?

Tags: ios, magicalrecord

```
// Setup magical record
[MagicalRecord setupCoreDataStack];

NSLog(@"Groups at startup: %d", [Group findAll].count);

[Group createEntity];
[[NSManagedObjectContext defaultContext] save];
```

I've placed this bit of code in my AppDelegate. Everytime I start up the app, I see the count as 0. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per MagicalRecord's github page..

> MagicalRecord provides a background saving queue so that saving all
>   data is performed off the main thread, in the background. This means
>   that it may be necessary to use MR_saveNestedContexts rather than the
>   typical MR_save method in order to persist your changes all the way to
>   your persistent store;

Comment: Deprecated. What do we use? `MR_saveToPersistentStoreAndWait`?